# Are Mirelurks intelligent?

Tags: fallout-3

During the [Wasteland Survival Guide quest chain](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Wasteland_Survival_Guide_(quest)), Moira Brown wonders whether Mirelurks are intelligent beings (have higher thought processes, society, culture, and so on).  But after you place the [Observer](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Observer) in the Mirelurk's nest, you never hear anything about it again.

There's plenty of circumstantial evidence to argue both sides of this question.  (For example, the blind aggression on sight is indicative of them simply being unthinking creatures, but the [Mirelurk Kings](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Mirelurk#Mirelurk_king) look suspiciously humanoid and intelligent.)  Is there any conclusive, canonical answer as to whether or not the Mirelurks are indeed an intelligent race?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: If Moira thinks so, it's probably wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official lore, at least nothing I can find, that suggests Mirelurks are intelligent or operate on anything beyond animal instinct.

Despite their humanoid appearance, there's no record of them ever attempting to communicate, using tools or building anything- the closest I could find was a single piece of concept art depicting a mirelurk wielding a [cudgel](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/File:Fo3_Mirelurk_King_Concept_Art_1.jpg). They don't appear to see man-made buildings and tunnels as anything more than caves.

They may have a social structure like many animals do but that does not prove intelligence.

Compare them to super mutants- even the dumber capital wasteland mutants- who can speak simple English, use and reload guns, and build crude forts out of junk.